# ISIS Simulation "is not running in real time due to excessive CPU load"

Tags: pic, microchip, proteus

Here is an animation showing the problem in action :

https://gfycat.com/ImmaterialNextGermanshorthairedpointer

I press Play, it works, I stop and play again, it stops working until I remove the connections and plug them in again.

Comment: I see a sequence of statements but no question.

Comment: Hmm, not much of a question, other than a "Why is this happening"?

Answer (score -1):

Decrease the clock speed of the microcontroller, this solves in most cases.

Comment: This answer is valid. Some hosts may not have the bandwidth to perform analysis of Real-time analysis of complex or fast rise-time processes.

Answer (score -2):

Le problème est dû a cause de l'alimentation en courant continue additionnée (DC générateur) ou multiple tension de 5V.

Google translate says:

*"The problem is due to the addition of DC power (DC generator) or multiple voltage of 5V."*

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. All questions and answers on EE.SE should be strictly in English.

Comment: "est dû à cause" isn't even proper French...